# Execute multiple templates conditionally

Tags: go

I have a webpage with two views, one for the anonymous user and one for the admin user. I want to display a navbar only for the admin user. Everything else remains the same for both the user types.

This is what I've tried so far

## main.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func BasicAuth(h httprouter.Handle, requiredUser, requiredPassword string) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        // Get the Basic Authentication credentials
        user, password, hasAuth := r.BasicAuth()

        if hasAuth && user == requiredUser && password == requiredPassword {
            // Delegate request to the given handle
            h(w, r, ps)
        } else {
            // Request Basic Authentication otherwise
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=Restricted")
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
    }
}

func Anonymous(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Name": "Anonymous"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func Admin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html", "admin.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Name": "Admin"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    user := "admin"
    pass := "1234"

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Anonymous)
    router.GET("/admin/", BasicAuth(Admin, user, pass))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{{ .Name }}</title>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function counter() {
                document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = "x: " + document.querySelectorAll('.x').length;
                document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = "y: " + document.querySelectorAll('.y').length;
                document.getElementById("z").innerHTML = "z: " + document.querySelectorAll('.z').length;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="counter()">
        {{ template "dashboard" }}
        <nav class="navbar fixed-bottom">
            <div class="container-fluid nav-justified">
                <span id="x" class="navbar-brand nav-item"></span>
                <span id="y" class="navbar-brand nav-item"></span>
                <span id="z" class="navbar-brand nav-item"></span>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

## admin.html

```
{{ define "dashboard" }}
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid nav-justified">
        <span class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/a">a</a>
        </span>
        <span class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/b">b</a>
        </span>
        <span class="nav-item">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/c">c</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</nav>
{{ end }}
```

My assumption was that because I did not pass in the admin.html template while executing templates for the anonymous user, that the dashboard template would not be parsed. However, I run into this error:

```
template: index.html:18:14: executing "index.html" at <{{template "dashboard"}}>: template "dashboard" not defined
```

How do I fix this, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the `dashboard` template conditionally with an `if` action:

```
{{ if eq .Name "Admin" }} {{ template "dashboard" }} {{ end }}
```

And the practice is to parse the template only once instead of parsing it on every request:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

func BasicAuth(h httprouter.Handle, requiredUser, requiredPassword string) httprouter.Handle {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        user, password, hasAuth := r.BasicAuth()

        if hasAuth && user == requiredUser && password == requiredPassword {
            h(w, r, ps)
        } else {
            w.Header().Set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=Restricted")
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusUnauthorized), http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
    }
}

func Anonymous(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    err := tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Name": "Anonymous"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

func Admin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    err := tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Name": "Admin"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
}

var (
    tmpl     *template.Template
    tmplOnce sync.Once
)

func main() {
    user := "admin"
    pass := "1234"

    tmplOnce.Do(func() {
        tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("index.html", "admin.html"))
    })

    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Anonymous)
    router.GET("/admin/", BasicAuth(Admin, user, pass))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Comment: This example is based on one authenticated user - `admin`. What if I have two users with different roles, say an `admin` and a `moderator`, and both can use their respective credentials to authenticate a protected route, but I want to hand them over to different handles (example `func Admin` and `func Moderator` after authentication in BasicAuth func?

Comment: Or rather hand them over to the same handle but execute the templates with different maps

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot compare with the user name? The answer compares with the user name only because it's the only available information in your demo. Most of the time, we should add a field like `authenticated bool`, and check this field.

Comment: Apologies for not being able to explain clearly. So, suppose my route is `/login/` and depending on whether an admin or a mod logs in (through the same route), they're redirected to the same func, although when the template in this func is executed, the map is either `map[string]string{"Name": "Admin"}` or `map[string]string{"Name": "Moderator"}` respectively.  How do I pass on the user type from basic auth to the handle it's handing over to?

Comment: Don't need to apologize. ^_^ `How do I pass on the user type from basic auth to the handle it's handing over to?` You can modify the func `Admin` to accept more parameters. If you are playing with the demo to learn something, it's okay to do things like this. But if this is a production code, I would recommend some mature frameworks that have this feature built in. For example, [gin](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin).